# Referer when redirect with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, referer

I have a HTML page A from which I open the HTML page B with `window.open`. I then redirect the HTML page B to HTML page C but I get the HTML page A as the referrer . I need to go onto page C with B as the referrer.

Comment: i use this script:
`code
    function newtab() 
    { 
    var w1 = window.open('https://www.google.fr');
    setTimeout(function(){ red(w1); }, 3000);
    } 
    function red(tab)
    {
    tab.location.assign('https://www.whatismyreferer.com');
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Because the main referer is Ahtml page.

```
you can use window.location.href



window.location.href example:

window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will take you to Google.
```

window.open() example:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com'); //This will open Google in a new window.
```